# ID for elements from reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a container

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class AlbumsShow extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.renderImage = this.renderImage.bind(this);
   }

   renderImage(){
         return this.props.images.map(image => (
            <li key={image.id}>
                <img alt="job" src={image.img} />
                <p className="album_title">Test</p>
            </li>
        ));
    }

    render(){
        return (
          <div>{this.renderImage()}</div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){

    return {
     images: state.album.albums[0].images,
    };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AlbumsShow);
```

I my reducer I have numbers of albums and every album has it is own ID.

I need to set *images: state.album.albums[**id**].images* instead of *images: state.album.albums[**0**].images*, because I have a lot of albums.
I don't know how connection with ID could be realized in code.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be that you not store the albums in an array and rather store them in an object, by that you can give unique keys to each albums and hence access the albums as per the key you want.

You can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to create copies of objects with new or updated values.

Read more [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html)

Comment: Yes, I store all my albums in object, it is InitialState in reducer and every album has it is own ID, but I don't know how I can hence access the albums as per the key.

Comment: If you are getting the ids correctly, then why don't you just use the particular id for the particular component, to know all ids, just `console.log(state.album.albums)` before the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting `images: state.ablum.albums[id].images`, You can put `albums: state.album.albums`, so that in your code you can use `this.props.albums[id]`.

Comment: I add full code of component to my question. When I add this.props.albums[id] to my code my console shows error.